# How to create JSON Schema for Name/Value structure?

Tags: java, javascript, json, jsonschema

My problem is that i am serializing the content of map to JSON.

In the output (JSON), i have object that follow key/name syntax rule.

The key is created from map key, and the name from the value.

Model Example:

```
  class Storage {
       Map<String,String> values = new HashMap<>();

      {
         map.put("key1","key1");
         map.put("key2","key2");
         map.put("key3","key3");
      }

    }
```

JSON Example object:

```
{
  key1=value1,
  key2=value2,
  key3=value3
}
```

---

JSON Schema:

```
{
  "name": "storage",
  "description": "Store of key values",
  "properties": {
    // How can we describe the properties if we do not know the name ?
   }
}
```

The issue is that i do not know what the values will be but i know that they will be some.

Can you help me to provide me the full definition of schema?

---

**Disclaimer:**

I know that this can be also serialized as

```
 {
    values: [
       {key="key1", value="value1"},
       {key="key2", value="value2"},
       {key="key3", value="value3"}
    ]
 }
```

but is do not want to have array in the JSON.

Comment: sounds like the properties you have would be an array of "key": <keyvalue> "value": < value value>.

Comment: I do not want to have an array of pairs. I would like to have the key=value as the part of object that is valid to have and easy to deserialize.

Comment: So you are asking how to specify name, value pairs for a situation in which you do not know the names a priori?  Can't be done. Anyway, isn't your goal to be able to reconstitute the HashMap?  In that case you would go through a loop adding Key, value anyway.

Comment: You might be right. But if there is a valid way to serialize and deserialize such object is should be possible to create a Schema for it. To advise people that can expect some object with undefined interiors.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Assuming your validator supports it you can use [patternProperties](http://json-schema.org/latest/json-schema-validation.html#rfc.section.6.19).

For the schema...

```
{
  "title": "Map<String,String>",
  "type": "object",
  "patternProperties": {
    ".{1,}": { "type": "string" }
  }
}
```

...and the document...

```
{
    "foo":"bar",
    "baz":1
}
```

...the value of property *foo* is valid because it is a string but *baz* fails validation because it is a number.

Comment: Even simpler: use `"additionalProperties": { "type": "string" }`.  This specifies that any properties not otherwise specified must satisfy the given schema.

Comment: ".{1,}" Using this solution for data with Map key values provided the answer to my problem. I'm glad you posted. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I used the Solution suggested by @augurar
"additionalProperties": { "type": "string" }

for AWS API Gateway Model .... and the SDK was able to generate the Map variable as required in Java / Android SDK

@Arne Burmeister - in my case - Solution 1 didnt worked as needed - although it didnt gave any error in the Model (Schema Created)